# UITableView Scroll automatically to the top after begin/end updates call for adjust height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I have a TableViewController that initialize my cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FIDPostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell for this indexPath
    [cell updateFonts];
    [cell loadDataWithPost:[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    cell.parentTableViewController = self;
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    [cell draw];
    if(self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
        //Do expand cell stuff
    } else{
        //DO closed cell stuff
    }

    return cell;
}
```

and that responds to heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
  NSString *reuseIdentifier = CellIdentifier;
    FIDPostTableViewCell *cell = [self.offscreenCells objectForKey:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FIDPostTableViewCell alloc] init];
        [self.offscreenCells setObject:cell forKey:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell for this indexPath
    [cell updateFonts];
    [cell loadDataForHeightCalculationWithPost:[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    [cell draw];

         if(self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
    return [cell calculateHeight] + 100;
} else{
    return [cell calculateHeight];
}


    }
```

**self.selectedIndex** is a int local variable of TableViewController

Each custom cell have inside a button, that respond to a selector when touched, this is my CustomViewCell code:

```
  self.expandSocialAction = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        self.expandSocialAction.backgroundColor = [FIDUIHelper fideniaLightBlue];
        [self.expandSocialAction addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.expandSocialAction];
```

and then:

```
-(void)selectRow:(id)sender{
    if(self.parentTableViewController.selectedIndex == self.indexPath.row){
        self.parentTableViewController.selectedIndex = -1;
    } else{
    self.parentTableViewController.selectedIndex = self.indexPath.row;
    }
    [self.parentTableViewController.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.parentTableViewController.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

The cell have a pointer to parent tableViewContorller: self.parentTableViewController.
All work fine, after beginUpdate and endUpdates call, the method heightForRowAtIndexPath is called ( i put a break point in ) and also che cell have the right height.

If i click the button on the first or second row the cell animate and change height fine, but if i scroll down the table and for example i click on the 6th row, the height change but the tableView scroll automatically to the first or second element.

Any suggestion?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method is part of the problem. Instead of performing the calculation, try to just use two constants in that method: one for expanded, one for collapsed. I'm wondering if the method is taking too long to execute and then thinks the height of the rows are `0`, then the calculation finally returns, but the `UITableView` scroll position is not updated.

Another suggestion might be that your `estimatedHeight` and `heightFor` methods are returning two vastly different values.

Comment: `estimatedHeight and heightFor methods are returning two vastly different values.` saved me!

Answer (score 0):

check if you have used `ScrollTORowAtIndexPAth` someWhere in your code

Comment: No i don't use that method